# Are there front looking mirror options?

Tags: mirrors

I have the standard drop handlebars on my road bike. When I'm in the lower position, my head is pointing down so my eyes are looking at the road and my front tire. Looking forward requires me to tilt my head up to an awkward angle and I often get a kink in my neck after a longish ride. Are there mirrors available which I could mount on my bike which would provide me a front facing view while still keeping my head down?

Comment: It would be very disorienting (and probably unsafe) to ride like this, because you would be seeing a mirror image. Also, your field of view would be quite limited, or it would be distorted because you'd . Not only that, correct me if I'm wrong here, but wouldn't the image be vertically flipped?

Comment: It's hard enough to find a passable back-looking mirror.

Comment: Are you wearing a helmet or hat with a peak? If so, the peak may be blocking your view, so you have to bend your neck more to see where you are going.

Comment: @vclaw - Yeah, I removed the visor that came attached (riveted -- grrrr) to my helmet because it blocked my forward view.

Comment: 1. Bike fit. 2. Yoga.

Comment: I doubt they exist - you may want a shallower drop bar though.

Comment: Does it have to be a mirror - tech could help - Google Glasses or a small 2.5" screen and a camera   (only half kidding)

Comment: How long is your "long ride"? And how long (time) have you been riding your road bike?

Comment: "When I'm in the lower position, my head is pointing down so my eyes are looking at the road and my front tire." You really shouldn't be looking at your front tire while on the drops. Most effective is to look several meters ahead of you. Use your peripheral vision to see what's going on under your front tire. Just my 0.2 cents.

Comment: There was a kickstarter for an unfortunately-named gadget, the Pediscope. It did not reach its funding goals.

Comment: If you cause an accident by riding with a mirror like this then you could be charged with "using an unsafe vehicle on the road" or similar.  Better to get a good bike fit, perhaps raise your front end.  If your helmet has a visor, remove/raise it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they exist, though they are expensive and meant for racing rather than for general purpose riding on regular roads. One example is the [View Speed Cyclops](http://www.shop.view-speed.com/View-Speed-Cyclops-Glasses-610098715948.htm) glasses. They take a lot of getting used to but in the arcane world of time-trial racing they have their adherents.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 for actually digging up something that vaguely meets the OP's specs.

Comment: Actually, similar glasses are available for rock climbers: http://cubelayglasses.co.uk/

Answer (score 4):

I would be very tempted to say that your bike isn't setup correctly for you. It shouldn't cause any back/neck issues after a long ride (although you don't say how long that is). If you handlebars/stem is of the correct length/height, then you shouldn't have any issues seeing in front of you- nor pains in these areas.

To answer your question- I am unaware of any mirrors, and this seems like it would be a very dangerous way to ride your bike.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for something like this and couldn't find anything, so I manufactured my own using a mirror, glass cutter, an old bike light frame with a hose clamp to attach it to the handlebars, and some construction adhesive. I used aluminum channel for trim around it and it worked quite well until someone stole my bike so now I have to make another.